# Can't use System.Windows.Forms;

Tags: c#, winforms, xamarin

I have referenced `System.Windows.Forms`, but Xamarin will not let me use it. 
It only allows me to use Windows.Input and Markup.

Comment: So are you looking for a workaround?

Comment: Xamarin is for IOS, it won't have windows.

Comment: Xamarin is the name of a company. Which of their products are you talking about? And what platform are you targeting?

Comment: I'm talking about Xamarin Studio (via Monodevelop).

Comment: Could you use System.Windows.Forms in your Xamarin project? @Statharas.903

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it is simply a visual issue, code compiles, even though half of it is marked red.